# jquery max-height and max-width returns wrong values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im having a problem with max-width and max-height.
lets say i have the following css rule:

```
img.item { max-width: 325px; max-height: 390px; }
```

and the following img in my document:

```
<img class="item" src="http://us.dorothyperkins.com/wcsstore/DorothyPerkinsUS/images/catalog/80000095_normal.jpg">
```

original image width x height is: 342 x 464

if i try and get with jquery the values for max-width and max-height i get them wrong.

```
$('img.item').css('max-width');
// returns 357px
$('img.item').css('max-height');
// returns 429px
```

any ideas on why is this? or how i can get the correct sizes?

if i use `$('img.item').width() and $('img.item').height()` i get the calculated values, not good for me.

thanks.

Comment: You should apply height and width to the img-tag itself.

Comment: but if i apply height and width to the image itself it wont maintain the correct proportion of the image size.

Comment: There must be something affecting this that isn't above, because this example works perfectly...  http://jsfiddle.net/HTC8J/  - Which browser are you using?

Comment: Agree @Archer. Israhack do you have padding on your element? What browser does this occur.

Answer (score 2):

I have check you code and add latest jquery, it works well with the correct result.
Please check my code here.

```js
alert($('img.item').css('max-width'));

alert($('img.item').css('max-height'));
```

```css
img.item { max-width: 325px; max-height: 390px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="item" src="http://us.dorothyperkins.com/wcsstore/DorothyPerkinsUS/images/catalog/80000095_normal.jpg">
```

There might me other reason is, Your image `max-height` and `max-width` might be **overwrite** by other `class`

Answer (score 1):

Strange results. I have created fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/JGwqY/ and there max-width and max-height values are correct.